How can I resolve ModuleNotFound Error when using Pytest in PyCharm
I am getting the below error when running the existing Selenium Python tests in PyCharm. Please let me know how to resolve this
C:\Users\<UN>\Documents\python\python.exe "C:/Users/<UN>/AppData/Local/JetBrains/PyCharm Community Edition 2024.1.1/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pycharm/_jb_pytest_runner.py" --path "C:\Users\<UN>\Downloads\Functional automation\myproj\Python scripts\test website\test_IS tests.py" 
Testing started at 23:11 ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\<UN>\AppData\Local\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2024.1.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pycharm\_jb_pytest_runner.py", line 17, in <module>
    from _jb_runner_tools import jb_patch_separator, jb_doc_args, JB_DISABLE_BUFFERING, \
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_jb_runner_tools'

Process finished with exit code 1

Empty suite


Tried to execute the python tests, but got this error on compilation itself. Normal python files are compiling fine, but have this issue only with pytests

Please provide your  file structure and pytest setup, so we can help you (i assume the module is just another .py file)

I have currently the same issue, I runned the tests with debugging mode and the tests run but somehow when runned normaly I get the same message as you. The file _jb_pytest_runner.py is on my pycharm on the right folder but somehow is not found. I know this is not a solution but this might help finding one.
Edit: I have contacted the pycharm support but they still havent been able to reproduce the error. In any case, I found a not so clean way to make pytest work. On _jb_pytest_runner.py on line 17 I added a sys.path.append("C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2024.2.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pycharm")
and then pytest worked. I know this is not a clean solution, but its something.
